# GOP size and Frames Per Second Relationship

Tags: video, encoding, h.264, frame-rate

Hi i don't have enough time since i've started exploring
image processing and video encoding theory so i came up
with some questions.
I would like to know if there is a relation (algebraic maybe) between the GOP size
chosen and the frames per second (fps) value of an encoded video 
(with H264 AVC codec used to encode).

Answer (score 2):

No direct relationship. Frames/second is the rate of image updates - faster or slower. Independently, sequence of images might be "grouped" into larger or smaller groups. Quite so often the chosen GOP values are measured in seconds, that is correlate with frame rate, but this is more a matter of convenience.